# Zapier CLI, using choices on inputFields does not show it in the form when creating new Zap

Tags: zapier, zapier-cli

I am following the docs from [zapier-platform-schema](https://github.com/zapier/zapier-platform-schema/blob/master/docs/build/schema.md) to set choices in the `hook` trigger `inputFields`, but they are not shown in the form when creating new Zap.

I do the following:

```
{
    key: 'booking',
    noun: 'Booking',
    display: {
        label: 'text',
        description: 'text',
        important: true
    },
    operation: {
        type: 'hook',
        inputFields: [
            {
                key: 'action',
                required: true,
                choices:  {
                    created: 'New booking placed',
                    updated: 'Booking amendment',
                    canceled: 'Booking canceled'
                }
            }
        ],
    }
};
```

Then I do `zapier push`. And when I am creating new Zap in the editor, after I select the integration project I see only the `booking` checkbox and not the choices form

Comment: does your `zapier push` complete successfully and do you refresh the editor after the push?

Comment: @xavdid no issue with the code, I was testing it in a wrong way. Zapier Support helped me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was solved, Zapier Support helped me. The code is correct, I just was testing it in a wrong way. I was looking for the select drop-down at an early stage of Zap creating page, after I selected the Trigger. Where the drop-down appears after I connect an account to the Zap.